# Understanding User defined Iterators

Tags: python

In the code below, I'm confused why `Hi3` never gets printed:

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.start = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        print "called __iter__", self.size
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.start < self.size:
            print 'Hi1'
            self.start = self.start + 1
            print 'Hi2'
            return self.start
            print 'Hi3'
        raise StopIteration

c = Counter(2)
for num in c:
    print num
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reach `print 'Hi3'` you need to go past a `return self.start` statement. Remember that the `return` statement exits the function immediately. (Maybe you were mixing up iterators and generators and thought about [yield](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) instead of `return`).